# C# - How to Stop a Loop When a Key is Pressed?

Tags: c#, loops, console-application

Currently I am using this code:

```
using System;

namespace Project
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            bool key = false;
            while (key == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Loop");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine, but I wanted to make the loop stop when a key is pressed. I tried this:

```
using System;

namespace Project
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            bool key = false;
            while (key == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Loop");
                {
                Console.ReadKey (true);
                key = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that just continues the loop when a key is pressed. Any solutions?

Comment: Your second code doesn't compile and doesn't continue the loop (its just blocking for a keypress).

Answer (score 10):

I suggest using [Console.KeyAvailable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 while (!Console.KeyAvailable) {
   Console.WriteLine("Loop");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Works great!