# Console.ReadLine() only works once despite it being in a while loop

Tags: c#, windows, while-loop, console, console-application

*To give some context for the code, I'm modifying the game "AssaultCube".*

So this is a console program. When it launches, you can type stuff in and if you type in "1", it'll start setting the health value to 999 in a loop. However, you can't type more stuff in because the loop isn't over, but in order to end the loop, I need to be able to type "1" to toggle it off. I want to be able to toggle this on and off each time I type in "1". It seems like a simple problem and I've been trying to get this to work for hours with no luck and my brain is fried. Thanks in advance and sorry if I was unclear in my explanation, I'm not good at those :D.

```
while (true)
        {
            string Select;
            Select = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Select == "1") //If the number "1" is typed, do stuff
            {
                int finalHealth = localPLayer + health; //Add the Base and Health addresses together

                if (healthToggle == false)
                {
                    healthToggle = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Unlimited Health activated\n");

                    while (healthToggle) //While Health Toggle is TRUE, do stuff
                    {
                        vam.WriteInt32((IntPtr)finalHealth, 999); //Set finalHealth to 999 in a loop, making you invincible
                        Thread.Sleep(100); //Let CPU rest
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    healthToggle = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Unlimited Health deactivated\n");

                    vam.WriteInt32((IntPtr)finalHealth, 100); //Set health value back to normal
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to Stop a Loop When a Key is Pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41542248/8967612), [Listen for key press in .NET console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app)

Comment: @41686d6564 Hmm... Not really, I'd run into the same problem either way. What I need to be able to do is essentially go to the start of the main loop while the other loop is still running inside it to activate other modifications to the game... if that makes sense? I think I need to figure out something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with 41686d6564, [Console.KeyAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_KeyAvailable) and [Console.ReadKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1) are definitely the way to go.

Try this out...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to quit, or 1 to start/stop.");
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            quit = true;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Unlimited Health activated\n");
            bool godMode = true;
            while (godMode)
            {
                // ... do something ...
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffff") + ": ...something ...");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
                    {
                        godMode = false;
                    }                            
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Unlimited Health deactivated\n");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```